# bijection between two sets each containing each other

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am just curious below shouldn't $g : A \rightarrow B$ be defined as $g : B \rightarrow A$ because of the fact that f is defined on some elements which might not include elements of A ?[image]

Comment: Note that $D_0 = B - A$.

Comment: We also have $|A| \le |B| \le |C|$ by containment and $|A|=|C|$ from the bijection hence $|A|=|B|=|C|$.

Comment: I posted an answer to this question. Was anything about my answer unclear? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct that it should be $g:B\to A$. The passage claims that we're defining a map $g:A\to B$ and that $g$ will be a bijection. But if we define $g$ in the way the passage says we should define $g$, then $g$ will not be a bijection, because it won't be onto $B$ (unless $A=B$). If we define $g:A\to B$ in the way the passage says to, then the Range of $g$ will be $B-(D_0\cup D_1)$.

On the other hand, we can use the definition from the quoted passage to define $g:B\to A$, and if we do so then $g$ will indeed be a bijection. So you're correct: it should be $g:B\to A$.

Comment: Yeah I fully agree with your reasoning.